# Changing thematic symbology based on an atlas feature reference

Tags: qgis, atlas-generator

I have created a layout atlas based on a geographic layer containing defined store 'catchments' (ie as polygons).

Each atlas 'page' shows just the relevant catchment region.

For each atlas feature, I  also want to customise a thematic representation of each store's market share by postcode. This runs from a separate layer which is based on postcode regions and has a field for each store showing the market share within each postcode.

I am trying to reference the field name (in the picture below the field name is 'Albury_mkt') dynamically as a concatenation of the atlas page name ('Albury') and the text string "_mkt".

If successful, each atlas page will show the thematic only for the relevant region.

I have tried to use the function  concatenate(@atlas_pagename,'_mkt') but this doesn't seem to parse properly.

[image: symbology example]

Comment: try concatenating using the || symbol: @atlas_pagename || '_mkt'

Comment: Testing this out, the output preview says 'Albury_mkt'. The expression output needs to be "Albury_mkt" - note the double quotes instead of single quotes.

Comment: Thanks csk, I think I am getting close, but as you say, my result is creating single quotes rather than the required double quotes.How can I convert the 'Albury_mkt' to "Albury_mkt"?

Comment: To be honest I couldn't figure this out. I tried: eval(); putting the expression in double quotes; concatenating double quotes before and after the expression; putting single quotes around double quotes and concatenating them to the expression. The closest I got was an output of '"Albury_mkt"'

Comment: If this was my project, at this point I would try setting it up a completely different way. Maybe by filtering the BB_postcode_master_2018 layer  based on the atlas_pagename variable. Or make a separate layer for each _mkt field, and use data-defined visibility for those layers.

Answer (score 3):

Try wrapping `eval()` around your expression to signal to QGIS that it's meant to be read as a field name, and not a text string.

e.g., `eval(@atlas_pagename || '_mkt')`

edit: Also I believe the function you should have been using was `concat()` not `concatenate()` though this may be a difference of versions

Comment: Excellent. That answers my question, although in my case there is still an issue with some atlas page names containing a space (but which are an underscore character when in the field heading). But I will post that as a separate question if I can't resolve.

Comment: Off the top of my head, try `replace(@atlas_pagename,' ','_')`?